# Does image on photo (for link under) look like larvae/cysts, or adult helminths (other parasites)?

Tags: physical-health

Here it's link to the photo

https://wampi.ru/image/RyEtECy

For 2 months, frequent constipation, abdominal pain, itching in the anus, nausea and weakness. In the feces, I repeatedly find white or yellowish spots in the form of dots or more (like lumps).
There was also intestinal constipation before, the stomach hurts after eating or before going to bed or just like that, at the bottom left or all over the lower part. 3 months ago, I often had a headache

Comment: You can upload the photo here, the link you posted is broken there's no photo there. Anyway, you should see a doctor, this site can't really help.

Comment: thank you for your answer